Kubernetes Pod Error - Pod Wont Start Up, No Logs for Debugging, Only Pod Description to work with
I'm deploying Sentry on Kubernetes and the front-end won't start up successfully. The pod has no logs to tell me why that is the case & the description isn't telling me a lot. All other pods are running well, apart from the sentry relay pod which relies on the web pod to work. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.
Service file
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: sentry
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: sentry
  creationTimestamp: "2024-04-30T08:59:16Z"
  labels:
    app: sentry
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: sentry-22.2.1
    heritage: Helm
    release: sentry
  name: sentry-web
  namespace: sentry
  resourceVersion: "45261180"
  uid: 6d78fdb0-737f-42c0-bfa4-f14713cd3fc9
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.171.247.137
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.171.247.137
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: sentry
    port: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: sentry
    role: web
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

Deployment file
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: sentry
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: sentry
  creationTimestamp: "2024-04-30T08:59:16Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: sentry
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: sentry-22.2.1
    heritage: Helm
    release: sentry
  name: sentry-web
  namespace: sentry
  resourceVersion: "45267824"
  uid: 4a8470e2-c3a8-4a2f-b1b8-b9273a2a67fc
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sentry
      release: sentry
      role: web
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config.yaml: 25085c2cd1786f4efc5805aff6ff11dc28baafdd5ca22b767c29c19f095299aa
        checksum/configYml: 44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a
        checksum/sentryConfPy: d5f85a6a8afbc55eebe23801e1a51a0fb4c0428c9a73ef6708d8dc83e079cd49
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: sentry
        release: sentry
        role: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - sentry
        - run
        - web
        env:
        - name: SNUBA
          value: http://sentry-snuba:1218
        - name: VROOM
          value: http://sentry-vroom:8085
        - name: SENTRY_SECRET_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: key
              name: ************
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          value: ************
        - name: SENTRY_EMAIL_PASSWORD
          value: ************
        image: getsentry/sentry:24.2.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 5
          httpGet:
            path: /_health/
            port: 9000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        name: sentry-web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 5
          httpGet:
            path: /_health/
            port: 9000
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 2
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/sentry
          name: config
          readOnly: true
        - mountPath: /var/lib/sentry/files
          name: sentry-data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: sentry-sentry
        name: config
      - name: sentry-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sentry-data
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2024-04-30T08:59:16Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2024-04-30T08:59:16Z"
    message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
    status: "False"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2024-04-30T09:09:17Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2024-04-30T09:09:17Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "sentry-web-7868d9bb96" has timed out progressing.
    reason: ProgressDeadlineExceeded
    status: "False"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1

Pod Description
Name:             sentry-web-7868d9bb96-qr7rw
Namespace:        sentry
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             ************
Start Time:       Tue, 30 Apr 2024 11:59:20 +0300
Labels:           app=sentry
                  pod-template-hash=7868d9bb96
                  release=sentry
                  role=web
Annotations:      checksum/config.yaml: 25085c2cd1786f4efc5805aff6ff11dc28baafdd5ca22b767c29c19f095299aa
                  checksum/configYml: 44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a
                  checksum/sentryConfPy: d5f85a6a8afbc55eebe23801e1a51a0fb4c0428c9a73ef6708d8dc83e079cd49
Status:           Running
IP:               10.168.27.13
IPs:
  IP:           10.168.27.13
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/sentry-web-7868d9bb96
Containers:
  sentry-web:
    Container ID:  containerd://815dda98ec79cedafb6e501d97fdd491bdd68c29e11165cb22779064629c590a
    Image:         getsentry/sentry:24.2.0
    Image ID:      docker.io/getsentry/sentry@sha256:22b122517698921926e7996ae0fd04a6c994dda160ab9ed1d963bacfa7ad2968
    Port:          9000/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      sentry
      run
      web
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 30 Apr 2024 13:16:06 +0300
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Tue, 30 Apr 2024 13:09:31 +0300
      Finished:     Tue, 30 Apr 2024 13:11:00 +0300
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  22
    Liveness:       http-get http://:9000/_health/ delay=10s timeout=2s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:      http-get http://:9000/_health/ delay=10s timeout=2s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Environment:
      SNUBA:                  http://sentry-snuba:1218
      VROOM:                  http://sentry-vroom:8085
      SENTRY_SECRET_KEY:      <set to the key 'key' in secret 'sentry-sentry-secret'>  Optional: false
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:      ************
      SENTRY_EMAIL_PASSWORD:  ************
    Mounts:
      /etc/sentry from config (ro)
      /var/lib/sentry/files from sentry-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-lrq7t (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      sentry-sentry
    Optional:  false
  sentry-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  sentry-data
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-lrq7t:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----     -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  21m (x160 over 75m)    kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.168.27.13:9000/_health/": dial tcp 10.168.27.13:9000: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  6m30s (x106 over 75m)  kubelet  Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.168.27.13:9000/_health/": dial tcp 10.168.27.13:9000: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff    103s (x211 over 65m)   kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container sentry-web in pod sentry-web-7868d9bb96-qr7rw_sentry(3cae0346-a538-4327-9233-d7e9909883d4)


Can you try temporarily removing LivenessProbe and ReadinessProbe? Or maybe increasing delaysecond or period second?

@MadaraUchiha still not showing any logs. The same error persists.
